# Osx Python 2.7 not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-wheel

I'm trying to install sling on a mac with python 2.7 and pip 10.0.1:

```
 sudo  pip install http://www.jbox.dk/sling/sling-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

but I received the error

```
 sling-1.0.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I also tried the -H flag as specified in other posts but it doesn't help. Is there any way I can install a linux whl on a mac? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install a linux wheel onto MacOS — that surely doesn't work. You have to find a wheel for your platform or compile from sources.